# Will this motor work?

Tags: electrical

I was gifted an old Craftsman miter saw. Before I get brushes and restore it, I would like to know if the motor will even work.

To me, it looks like there's melted crud between some of the commutator bars and there's discoloration around it. See pic. Is that going to be a problem?

[image]

Comment: You can saw out the crud in the slots, with care, if you won't have it looked at by an experienced motor mechanic. Of course, if it came to you not running with no brushes, that might be a clue. I got new brushes for a saw I thought needed them, without having pulled the old brushes, and found that the old brushes were fine and the armature was shot (and cost more than a whole new saw.) So much for the wear part going first...

Answer (score 2):

So find an old shop and get the armature tested on a growler.

Probably need to sort that commutator out first though.

If that tests out then check the motor windings.

Then new bearings, reassemble and trst.

Comment: So are you thinking the commutators are likely busted? I'd like to avoid bringing this into a shop since I got it free. It'd probably be cheaper to buy the brushes than to get a technician to look at it.

Is there a way to check by myself? I have a handheld multimeter and can do things like check resistances.

Comment: So all you need is a lathe to turn the com up and then somehow generate a magnetic field so you can check the windings - but find the pairs and use a multimeter. The com shows a lot of damage...

Comment: Ahh... ok. Thank you for the extra comments! Sounds doable, but with a bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that unusual as when the motor is stopped via dynamic braking. All of the stopping current passes through the brushes, much more than normal running current.  First check the field windings and be sure they are all at about the same resistance and are not grounded to the case. That communitator needs to be turned down until it is clean, not doing that is a waste of time and effort. The slots between the bars also need to be cleaned and no shorts. Than an ohm meter connect it to the shaft and used to test each copper bar, all communicator bars should show infinite resistance. A megger or hi-pot is better if you have access to one.  At that point it is ready to test. If you are not comfortable with this or do not have access to the tools the best thing is to take it to a motor shop or replace it. If you do the repair putting in the wrong brushes can cause this type of damage. Be sure to install new bearings, that will save future problems.

I would use fine sandpaper to finish the polishing after turning it. You need a lath to keep it flat and even across and also round and balanced. I to not know your skill set but that will take a lot of sanding the groves are deep. If this is not done properly it will be short lived and there is not a lot of extra copper there.

Comment: Awesome! This saw does have dynamic braking! Field windings look good, and no shorts. Could I use sandpaper to clean the commutator bars?